# C string is being printed out of bounds

Tags: c

This code breaks the main string stringone whenever it finds the substring aaa in it. This code is doing that but it is printing out bounds and not stopping at the null character.

The output i got is this

> ```
> who cares if 
> one more light goes out 
> in the sky of a million 
> stars, 
> well i do if the star is you 
> ;<@����P����p���Xz��������p���0zRx
>                                             ����+zRx
>                                                               �$����FJ
>                                                                            �?;*}D���� \�����A�C
>   D|���eB�B�E �B(�H0�H8�M@r8A0A(B BB�8����p
> ```

I don't understand why, am i skipping the NULL character in the line where i update the string ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char *stringone = "who cares if aaa one more light goes out aaa in the sky of a million aaa stars, aaa well i do if the star is you \0";

    char *breaker = "aaa";

    while(stringone)
    {
        while(stringone != strstr(stringone, breaker) || stringone == NULL)
        {
            printf("%c",*stringone);
            stringone++;
        }

        stringone = stringone + strlen(breaker) + 1;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to start with the second word "cares" and debug the code.

Comment: `stringone` never becomes NULL. What is `stringone == NULL` supposed to accomplish? If you want to check whether you've reached the NUL terminator, shouldn't you be checking a `char` instead of a `char *`?

Comment: You just read off the end of the string. I think you meant to write `&& *stringone` instead of `|| stringone == NULL`, but even in that case , you also need to not do `stringone = stringone + strlen(breaker) + 1`

Comment: You don't need to add an explicit null byte at the end of your string literal. It being a string literal means that it is added for you. Also the null pointer constant `NULL` is not a null byte `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to fix the issue.

Comment: Also, you probably meant to check for `*stringone != NULL` rather than `stringone == NULL` (note you probably wanted to use `&&` here rather than `||` because of that).

Comment: Yea at first i thought after the string is empty the pointer will be pointing towards a NULL. Didn't know that part :(

Comment: @Toqoz `*stringone != NULL` is a comparison between a pointer and an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use strtok function. See the example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char stringone[200] = "who cares if aaa one more light goes out aaa in the sky of a million aaa stars, aaa well i do if the star is you";
    char breaker[10] = "aaa";
    char *token = strtok(stringone, breaker);

    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("\n %s", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, breaker);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strtok()` doesn't work that way.  `strtok()` can't be used to break a string up by using a string as a delimiter.

Comment: Someone voted this up?!?!  This answer is **wrong**. [RTFM](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html):  "A sequence of calls to *strtok()* breaks the string pointed to by *s* into a sequence of tokens, **each of which is delimited by a byte** from the string pointed to by *sep*."  Using `strtok()` per this answer will break up the string on every `'a'` **character** and not on any `"aaa"` **string**.

Comment: *It works.* Only if you consider breaking the string up on all `'a'` characters is the same as breaking the string up on all `"aaa"` **strings**.  That's a very poor definition of "works".

Comment: But it break on all "aaa" strings. Did you tested the code that i put?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `stringone != strstr(stringone, breaker)` fails only if the string `breaker` is at the start of `stringone`. The code does print the characters as expected as long as there is a match, but when there is no longer a match, `strstr` returns `NULL` an the condition continues to evaluate to true even beyond the end of `stringone`.

The code has undefined behavior: it prints unpredictable characters and will eventually crash at some point because the continue `while (stringone)` is unlikely to ever fail.

Here is how you can fix the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *stringone = "who cares if aaa one more light goes out aaa "
                            "in the sky of a million aaa stars, aaa well i"
                            " do if the star is you \0";
    const char *breaker = "aaa";
    const char *p;

    while ((p = strstr(stringone, breaker)) != NULL) {
        /* print the substring before the breaker */
        printf("%.*s\n", (int)(p - stringone), stringone);
        /* skip the breaker */
        stringone = p + strlen(breaker);
    }
    /* no separator left: print the rest of the string */
    printf("%s\n", stringone);
    return 0;
}
```